# Pandas - write out and read back a single column (export/import)

Tags: python, pandas

This feels like a vey basic operation that I'm missing? I want to write out a single column of a dataframe to a text file, manually clean it up a bit, and read the new version back into the dataframe (writing over the old data).

I wrote out the column data to CSV, with an index:

```
df['Systems'].to_csv('systems.csv', index=True)
```

The first five rows of the CSV look like this:

```
,Systems
0,A
1,B
2,C
3,D
4,E
```

Now I'm trying to get it back into the column, preserving the indexing:

```
df = pd.read_csv('systems_clean.csv',  encoding='utf-8', sep=',', header=1, index_col=1, usecols=['Systems']))
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Apologies if this is totally basic. Ive been searching for hours.

Comment: indexing is zero based try `df = pd.read_csv('systems_clean.csv',  encoding='utf-8', sep=',', header=1, index_col=0, usecols=['Systems']))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

indexing is zero based and in fact a lot of the params you passed are defaulted anyway so this should work:

```
df = pd.read_csv('systems_clean.csv',  encoding='utf-8', index_col=0)

In [3]:
import pandas as pd
import io
t=""",Systems
0,A
1,B
2,C
3,D
4,E"""
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), index_col=0)

Out[3]:
  Systems
0       A
1       B
2       C
3       D
4       E
```

Comment: Thanks! I got so crossed-eyed at the end I starting throwing everything in, i.e. default params, just in case. Your answer worked a charm.

Comment: Uh-oh... so the read-in column seems to have replaced the entire dataframe. I now only have one column: "Systems". How would I read it in and preserve all other columns. Is it `df[Systems] = pd.read_csv...` ?

Comment: you need to access just the column `df[Systems] = pd.read_csv()['Sytems']` or df[Systems] = pd.read_csv(...., squeeze=True)`.

Comment: Thanks! Just tried this and it worked perfectly `df['Systems'] = pd.read_csv('systems_clean.csv',  encoding='utf-8', index_col=0)['Systems']`. Cleaned data appeared in column Systems and all other columns untouched.

Answer (score 1):

1. You're using a lot of defaults (header, encoding, sep) that are unnecessary.
2. You should index from 0, not 1

`df = pd.read_csv('systems_clean.csv', index_col=0)`